# AJAX Global Array Storage

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, global

Long story short, I'm trying to store corresponding data values from a JSON returning AJAX into these global arrays. I know that the arrays are constructing correctly because I've put alerts within AJAX, but when I put it outside the AJAX, the array is still undefined.

How can I export either the entire popData JSON object to work on it and store the values in the global arrays or get the populating of the arrays in the AJAX to carry outside the call? I need these arrays to be accessible by another function to compare the population values to a narrow range of values selected by the user--if anyone wants to suggest a better way of doing this, but it has to pull the population values onLoad which is already done in the HTML. I think this is the most streamlined way to do that with the fewest AJAX calls on the server, but I'm open to suggestions! :D

```
    var popProducers = new Array();
    var popProducersCount = new Array();


    function getPopulationInfo(){

        $.ajax({
            url:phpURL,
            cache:false,
            dataType:"json",
            data: { },
            success:function(popData){

                for (i=0;i<popData.length;i++){

                    //producers and producersCount should be the same length at all times!
                    //If current producer name isn't in array already
                    if(popProducers.indexOf(popData[i].ProducerName) == -1){
                        //add new element to represent new producer quantity (producerCount.length returns number of elements in the array, thus if there are no elements = 0 thus making index 0 equal to 1 and so on)
                        popProducersCount[popProducersCount.length] = 1;
                        //Adds the producer name to the list of producers
                        popProducers[popProducers.length] = popData[i].ProducerName;
                    } else {
                        //Otherwise, it will increment the index of the producersCount array corresponding with the pre-existing producer name's index by 1
                        popProducersCount[popProducers.indexOf(popData[i].ProducerName)] += 1;
                    }


                }

            }
        });

        alert("Population Data Alert: " + popProducers);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.ajax()` and its underlaying `XMLHttpRequest()` create **asyncronous** requestes by default. That just means, your `alert()` statement is encountered before your `success` handler.

Easy solution here, move that `alert()` into the `success` handler at the very bottom.

If you want to deal with it in a more apropriate way, you could use jQuerys `Deferred` objects in a way like

```
function getPopulationInfo(){
    return $.ajax({
       // lots of stuff
    });
 }
```

and then call it like

```
getPopulationInfo().done(function() {
    alert("Population Data Alert: " + popProducers);
});
```

by returning the `.ajax()` method we implcitly return a `Deferred object`. Long story short, you can pass in some additional callbacks for `success` (.done()), `error` (.fail()) and `complete` (.always())

Comment: Oddly enough, when I moved the alert into the other function, it worked. So because the AJAX is asynchronous, the alert() call was simply made before the arrays had actually populated?

Comment: And then, how I can I make the script wait until the call is completed? There must be some option or parameter that can facilitate that, no?

Comment: @superspartan999: you indeed could force the request to be syncronous by adding an additional attribute to `.ajax()`, that is `async: false`. However, this is deprecated by jQuery 1.8 and its pretty bad doing it. It'll freeze and lockdown the browser UI until the request finishes. So its a much better and cleaner solution, to work with callbacks like described above.

Comment: you're welcome dude, I really hope you choosed to go with the callback solution anyway :-)